# Is shim secure if new MOK entried can be added without a password?

Tags: physical-access, secure-boot

I'm trying to understand how `shim` is considered secure.

Shim is a signed bootloader that allows to load any image (at a fixed path in the EFI System Partition) as long as its hash is added to a MOK (machine owner's key) list, which is stored in a UEFI variable.

If it cannot verify the hash, it will open a menu where the user can select a file to be added to the MOK. This procedure is very quick and does not require a password, even when the BIOS settings are password-protected.

An attacker with only two minutes physical access can boot from a removable drive, replace the image and reboot again to add it to the MOK. Though it requires physical access, the procedure can be performed extremely quickly.

The question is: Am I missing something? Is this outside the scope of what secure boot is supposed to protect?